# Problem with number of rows in a dataset

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting, report, birt

My new problem is the following: an SQL query to a database (DB2) returns 1500 rows but BIRT shows me only 500 in the dataset-editor. To count them I used a computed column (Integer) with the following logic:

```
Total.count(row["VPK"])
```

I'm using the RCP-Designer (BIRT 2.1.3). How can i get the other rows as well?

Answer (score 3):

In the RCP-Designer preview tab It only ever shows the first 500 rows. Mainly for performance I think. In Eclipse 3.5 (Ganymeade) you can go to Preferences->Report Design->Preview->Data and change the number of rows outputed there.

Or you can try launching as html or web-viewer, and that might not do the 500 row limit.

Once you run it in the correct runtime it wont limit the rows to 500.